# Can't go past the grub screen

Tags: grub2, read-only

I am going to preface this with the fact that I am extremely new to Ubuntu, so I don't know much.

When I start up my computer it takes me to

> GNU GRUB version 2.02~beta2-9ubuntu1

Not knowing what I should do, I press **Ubuntu*. It then gives me a bunch of lines that say `[FAILED]`, `[ OK ]`, or `[DEPEND]` then it just stops and says:

```
Ubuntu 14.04.2 LTS Elitebook tty1.

Elitebook login: [ 49.438486] systemd-readahead[206]: Failed to open pack file: Read-only file system
```

Could someone tell me what's going on, and how I should resolve this?